# Why $H(A)=H(C)$ where $C$ is $A$ with an additional parity bit?

Tags: channelcoding, information-theory

Let $A=\{00,01,10,11\}$ with equal probabilities for each symbol, and $B=\{0, 1\}$ be a parity generator such that 
$$
b=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if} \,\, a=00 \quad \text{or} \quad a=11 \\
1, & \text{if} \,\, a=01 \quad \text{or} \quad a=10
\end{cases}
$$
Now assume we transmit $(a_i,bj)$ where $a_i$ is a symbol in $A$ and $b_j$ is the parity bit associated with it. I calculated the entropy for $A$ as follows:
$$
H(A)=4 [4 \log_2(4)]=2
$$
and to calculate the entropy of the new symbols, call it alphabet $C=\{000,011,101,110\}$, we need the probabilities:
$$
p_c(0)=\mathbb{P}(a=00 \, \text{and} \, b=0)=\mathbb{P}(a=00)\mathbb{P}(b=0 \mid a=00)=\mathbb{P}(a=00)=1/4
$$
Similarly, $p_c(1)=p_c(2)=p_c(3)=p_c(0)=1/4$, the entropy of $C$ is
$$
H(C)=4 [4 \log_2(4)]=2=H(A)
$$
How is this the case? We have more bits per symbols in $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the entropy represents *information quantity*, or if being measured in bit, *the smallest number of bits per symbol* we need to represent a source.

The source $A$ contains $4$ equiprobable symbols hence it is obvious that we need $\log_2(4) = 2$ bits per symbol to represent the source.

The source $C$ is simply $A$ with its [parity bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) hence no new information is added. We have more bits per symbols, but the number of *information bits* is unchanged.

In communications, these additional bits are added to scope with error of transmissions.